# Website root not php installation root

Tags: php

This is section of code that I have put in /pgen/admin

```
<h1><b>List of saved text files:</b></h1>
<?php
$directory = "/pgen/saves/";
$phpfiles = glob($directory . "*.html");
$id = 1;

foreach ($phpfiles as $phpfile) {
    $date = " last modified/date created: " . date ("F d Y H:i:s.", filemtime($phpfile));
    echo $id.". <a href=$phpfile>".basename($phpfile)."</a>" .$date."<br>";
    $id ++;
}
?>
```

The `$directory` variable is supposed to be the root of the webpage plus /pgen/saves/.
I have tried using `$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/pgen/saves"`.
Also, if I browse using a ftp client, it shows this page is located at `/public_html/pgen/admin/` because I am using a 3rd party hosting service.
The code is supposed to list the files in the `/pgen/saves` folder but the code itself is in the `/pgen/admin` folder. I've searched everywhere and since I'm new at php, I don't know what to do.

Comment: make a test.php file, and inside that file put <?php phpinfo(); ?> execute the file. Will contain all your path info. Then learn how to use it!

Comment: Also if I echo $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] I get: `/usr/local/apache/htdocs` and when I run the code I get: 'Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/a2820539/public_html/pgen/admin/browse.php on line 7'

Comment: Thank you, worked perfectly. Found the _SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"] and was able to figure it out!

Comment: Great! See my answer below as well to address the foreach() error. Will bite you again later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would be better off to add some error checking/validation to your efforts. When using a foreach() method on an array, you must be aware that it is trusting you to pass it a legit array. If the value passed is not an array, it will try to use it and fail.

```
$directory = "/pgen/saves/";
$phpfiles = glob($directory . "*.html");
$id = 1;

// Error if no files are found
if (!is_array($phpfiles) && count($phpfiles) <= 0) {
    die('no files found');
}

// Otherwise, continue on
foreach ($phpfiles as $phpfile) {
    $date = " last modified/date created: " . date ("F d Y H:i:s.", filemtime($phpfile));
    echo $id.". <a href=$phpfile>".basename($phpfile)."</a>" .$date."<br>";
    $id ++;
}
```